# Pair students whose ratings differ no less than a given minimum?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

Example:

6 Students with this rankings :-> [3,4,5,2,1,1]

I need to pair those students and his rankings differ no less than 3.
Solution: [4,1],[5,2] -> I can perform 2 pairs maximum.

My algorithm can't perform correctly the solution for different inputs:

```
def maxPairs(skillLevel, minDiff):
    pairs = []
    for x in skillLevel:
        for y in skillLevel:
            if abs(x-y) >= minDiff and [x,y] not in pairs and [y,x] not in pairs:
                pairs.append([x,y])
                skillLevel.remove(x)
                skillLevel.remove(y)
                break

    return len(pairs)
```

Any tips?

Comment: You could build a graph, where the nodes are students, and there is an edge between two students if their rankings differ no less than 3. Then calculate a maximal matching in this graph by using e.g. the Ford Fulkerson algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching

Comment: Can you show us the different inputs? Can you share the link where you are trying? I suppose sort and binary search for each element's partner should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the students by ranking, and then compare each with its next, throwing out the bottom one if it does not work.

In your example your students start off ordered:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

After you sort them by ranking they are ordered

```
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Then you can pair `(4, 5)` because their ranks differ by `0`, and pair `(1, 2)` because their ranks differ by `1`.  Then `5` is left over.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
def maxPairs(skillLevel, minDiff):
    tagSkill = [[student, skill] for student, skill in enumerate(skillLevel)]
    tagSkill.sort(key= lambda x : x[1])
        # match the students that have minumum difference first

    pairs = []
    for student_a, skill_a in tagSkill:
        for student_b, skill_b in tagSkill:
            if abs(skill_a - skill_b) >= minDiff and student_a != student_b:
                pairs.append([skill_a, skill_b])
#               pairs.append([student_a, student_b]) # uncoment for pairs be students indexes
                tagSkill.remove([student_a, skill_a])
                tagSkill.remove([student_b, skill_b])
                break

    return len(pairs)
```

as btilly said I guess the problem is that you were checking for matching skill levels and then discarding these skill levels instead of the students.
I also guess that btilly suggestion to sort by skill levels is to avoid matching distant levels first and then not catching the maximum matching combinations.
I hope this helped, although I'm sure there must be a better way instead of a nested for loop

Comment: The problem is that he was matching people almost randomly, and sometimes did not find a maximal matching.  My approach will always find a maximal matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int res=0;
    sort(skillLevel.begin(),skillLevel.end());
    vector<int> minArr(skillLevel.begin(),skillLevel.begin()+skillLevel.size()/2);
    vector<int> maxArr(skillLevel.begin()+skillLevel.size()/2,skillLevel.end());
    
    int i=0,j=0;
    
    while(i<minArr.size() && j<maxArr.size()){
        if(abs(minArr[i]-maxArr[j])<minDiff){
            j++;
        }
        else{
            res++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    return res;
```